# Make expandable search form in Bootstrap navbar appear on top of everything else when width not enough

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

[My JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/pemequsini/1/edit?html,output)

I'm trying to add a search button to the `navbar-right` portion of my Bootstrap `nav` which when clicked will expand to a search form (essentially the same button including an `input` tag).

I seem to be facing some issues:

- The button is not aligned with the other nav items
- When the screen is resized and the button is clicked (to trigger the 'expansion'), the search form no longer appears on the same line with the other nav items (see the JS Bin link with, e.g. the width of the output set to 769px)

I have tried messing around with `z-index` so that the search form appears to be 'on top' of other items it would be otherwise overlapping but to no avail. How can I accomplish this? And is there a way to make the expanding/collapsing appear more seamless?

Comment: [Here's the link](https://jsbin.com/pemequsini/1/edit?html,output) to a JS Bin where I was experimenting. Didn't want to paste all that code here.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search-button,#search-icon").click(function(){
        $(".hide1").toggle();
    });
});
```

give hide1 class to two right most li

```
      <li class="hide1"><a href="#" target="_blank">Link</a></li>
      <li class="hide1"><a href="#">Another link</a></li>
```

use this jquery function you will get the needed result.

Comment: i think this does the trick i will try it out when i'm home, thanks